# android every new pid (id) entered then refresh listview . How i do this?

Tags: php, android, listview

my code . please help me . i'm beginner . php json andriod 
Mainactivity java
 please help me . when data change listview update automaticly and real time show my android app please help me

```
  package com.example.aaa111;




    public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        // URL to get contacts JSON
        private static String url = "http://test.pokupat.net/get_all_products.php";

        // JSON Node names




        private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
        private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
        private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

        // contacts JSONArray
        JSONArray contacts = null;

        // Hashmap for ListView
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            ListView lv = getListView();
    // refresh function if this true ..
             Handler handler = new Handler();

                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                //do anything
                    new GetContacts().execute();

                }
                }, 10000);

            // Listview on item click listener
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // getting values from selected ListItem
                    String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                            .getText().toString();
                    String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid))
                            .getText().toString();


                    // Starting single contact activity
                    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            SingleContactActivity.class);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

                    startActivity(in);

                }
            });

            // Calling async task to get json uyffuyfuyfuy fyuf yfuy fuf uyfuy
            new GetContacts().execute();
        }

        /**
         * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
         * */
        private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                // Showing progress dialog
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();

            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                // Creating service handler class instance
                ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

                // Making a request to url and getting response
                String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

                Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

                if (jsonStr != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                        // Getting JSON Array node
                        contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                        // looping through All Contacts
                        for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                            String pid = c.getString(TAG_PID);



                                                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                            HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                            contact.put(TAG_PID, pid);



                            // adding contact to contact list
                            contactList.add(contact);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                // Dismiss the progress dialog
                if (pDialog.isShowing())
                    pDialog.dismiss();

                        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                MainActivity.this, contactList,
                                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_PID
                                         }, new int[] { R.id.name,
                                        R.id.pid});

                        setListAdapter(adapter);



            }

        }

    }
```

refresh background please

Comment: You may have better luck using an Android developer support site in a language that is more comfortable for you. I have many listed at http://www.andglobe.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below

```
ListView lv = getListView();
```

Add

```
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            MainActivity.this, contactList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_PID
                                     }, new int[] { R.id.name,
                                    R.id.pid});

                    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Declare your adapter as a private variable

```
private SimpleAdapter adapter;
```

Then in your onPostExecute method call

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Rather than setting a new adapter each time with every call, you simply want to let the adapter know that new data has been added. This will then tell your list view to reevaluate itsself, and then you will see the new data appear.

Comment: how i do ? I want refresh my listview every minute. Please help me